# How to get full file get response from Google Drive V3

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api

The Google drive v2 seams to return a full file resource by default when I preform a file.Get.  However when I make the same request against V3 even though the documentation states it should return a file resource it is only returning a partial file resource.

```
GET /drive/v2/files/0B5pJkOVaKccEVEsybFA2WjJjQ1k?access_token={Token}
```

Returns the full file

```
{
  "mimeType": "text/plain", 
  "version": "416164", 
  "appDataContents": false, 
  "thumbnailLink": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/UE-d50Sda_j2pT1dzw8Ll1r7W2gYZNrofX2YS-VKG7Ykl4FAqe9NPPNPA3HX3PBdhQ8uow=s220", 
  "labels": {
    "restricted": false, 
    "starred": false, 
    "viewed": false, 
    "hidden": false, 
    "trashed": false
  }, 
  "explicitlyTrashed": false, 
  "lastModifyingUserName": "Linda Lawton", 
  "writersCanShare": true, 
  "owners": [
    {
      "picture": {
        "url": "https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-a1CWlFnA5xE/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAdVM/sHkU9F-AwwQ/s64/photo.jpg"
      }, 
      "kind": "drive#user", 
      "displayName": "Linda Lawton", 
      "permissionId": "6030588225573437243", 
      "isAuthenticatedUser": true, 
      "emailAddress": "xxxxx@gmail.com"
    }
  ], 
  "id": "0B5pJkOVaKccEVEsybFA2WjJjQ1k", 
  "lastModifyingUser": {
    "picture": {
      "url": "https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-a1CWlFnA5xE/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAdVM/sHkU9F-AwwQ/s64/photo.jpg"
    }, 
    "kind": "drive#user", 
    "displayName": "Linda Lawton", 
    "permissionId": "06030588225573437243", 
    "isAuthenticatedUser": true, 
    "emailAddress": "xxxxx@gmail.com"
  }, 
  "title": "deleteme.txt", 
  "ownerNames": [
    "Linda Lawton"
  ], 
  "etag": "\"dyf6dc5nFpQUIZ2nJvOu2LyLJk8/MTQ4MTU0MTI1NzI2MQ\"", 
  "parents": [
    {
      "isRoot": true, 
      "kind": "drive#parentReference", 
      "id": "0AJpJkOVaKccEUk9PVA", 
      "selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/0B5pJkOVaKccEVEsybFA2WjJjQ1k/parents/0AJpJkOVaKccEUk9PVA", 
      "parentLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/0AJpJkOVaKccEUk9PVA"
    }
  ], 
  "shared": false, 
  "originalFilename": "deleteme.txt", 
  "description": "Test Description", 
  "webContentLink": "https://drive.google.com/uc?id=0B5pJkOVaKccEVEsybFA2WjJjQ1k&export=download", 
  "editable": true, 
  "embedLink": "https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5pJkOVaKccEVEsybFA2WjJjQ1k/preview?usp=drivesdk", 
  "markedViewedByMeDate": "1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z", 
  "quotaBytesUsed": "150", 
  "modifiedDate": "2016-12-12T11:14:17.261Z", 
  "createdDate": "2016-12-12T11:14:17.261Z", 
  "md5Checksum": "8034035d0be478ab4e4c9bed279a5ff6", 
  "iconLink": "https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/doclist/images/icon_10_text_list.png", 
  "kind": "drive#file", 
  "alternateLink": "https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5pJkOVaKccEVEsybFA2WjJjQ1k/view?usp=drivesdk", 
  "copyable": true, 
  "modifiedByMeDate": "2016-12-12T11:14:17.261Z", 
  "downloadUrl": "https://doc-00-38-docs.googleusercontent.com/docs/securesc/1mngaurn1r7pdnvlih02e6t9l8me2de5/5h0plr5pqk919iiraojovqrovifi85g7/1481702400000/06030588225573437243/06030588225573437243/0B5pJkOVaKccEVEsybFA2WjJjQ1k?e=download&gd=true", 
  "userPermission": {
    "kind": "drive#permission", 
    "etag": "\"dyf6dc5nFpQUIZ2nJvOu2LyLJk8/-EUeXLzWA6FGgRjCErcDZHhfLzg\"", 
    "role": "owner", 
    "type": "user", 
    "id": "me", 
    "selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/0B5pJkOVaKccEVEsybFA2WjJjQ1k/permissions/me"
  }, 
  "spaces": [
    "drive"
  ], 
  "fileExtension": "txt", 
  "headRevisionId": "0B5pJkOVaKccEMW0yMitzcklkaWtFZ3FIS1l6Q2x5RGpKQkNjPQ", 
  "selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/0B5pJkOVaKccEVEsybFA2WjJjQ1k", 
  "fileSize": "150"
}
```

However when I make the same request against V3

```
GET /drive/v3/files/0B5pJkOVaKccEVEsybFA2WjJjQ1k?access_token={Token}
```

It returns only partial metadata

```
{
  "mimeType": "text/plain", 
  "kind": "drive#file", 
  "id": "0B5pJkOVaKccEVEsybFA2WjJjQ1k", 
  "name": "deleteme.txt"
}
```

I have found that by adding the fields parameter I can request additional ones from V3.  however I cant seam to find a way of returning all of the fields in one request.

> fields
>     Selector specifying a subset of fields to include in the
>   response.
>   For more information, see the partial response section
>   in the Performance Tips document. Use for better performance.

Its one get request so I am not concerned with performance I just need to see all the data for this file.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

After digging around in the documentation I managed to find a [comment](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/performance#partial).

> Use wildcards in field selections, if needed.
>   For example: fields=items/pagemap/* selects all objects in a pagemap.

So I tried this.

```
GET /drive/v3/files/0B5pJkOVaKccEVEsybFA2WjJjQ1k?access_token={Token}&fields=*
```

Sure enough it returned the full File resource.

Solution was to add `fields=*` to the request.   Personally I think this should be default.

Comment: It's an attempt to improve performance. As the file resource evolves to include more and more properties, some of which are potentially expensive to fetch or derive, or can clog up Googfle's pipes,  it makes sense to force the developer to specify only those properties she needs for her app.

Comment: I get 1000 rows of Google Analytics data which at this time can contain 7 dimensions and 10 metrics. And you think the drive team is worried about the load a single get of meta data will return.    Even if they add 100 new fields I don't think Google is going to feel it.

Comment: Too bad this isn't documented in https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/get

Comment: it's not documented because they would rather you use filtering.    I would rather just get everything